# Counting mentions in a Slack Channel

Tags: python, json, slack-api

I'm trying to run analytics around mentions in a designated slack channel. How many times someone is tagged vs how often they reply to the thread. I have the scopes necessary to pull the conversations history via the API but am not sure how to clean the data to tagged vs responded. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. The community here is ready to help you, but your question is too broad for the scope of this forum. Please break your problem down into specific issues to ask about. Please also include your current best code in the question.

Comment: Having said that: I wrote a Python script recently to convert Slack messages into PDF. It uses a lot of the same concepts, like retrieving messages from channels an d threads, parsing a message for the user mention and reading all the properties that can contain text (and mentions). Check it out and feel free to steal what you need. It's open source: [slackchannel2pdf](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackchannel2pdf) - e.g.: you find the parser for user mentions in `slackchannel2pdf._transform_text`